# Add data to class with `__slots__`, wrap it?

Tags: python, class, subclass, wrapper

I have a Python object `a` of class `A` which is out of my control. I don't know anyhing about `A`, inclusing its `__init__`. I would like to add some data to `a`, but `__slots__` in `A` prevents me from doing so.  I'd like to work around it *somehow*.

The object with the extra data needs to function just like an instance of `A`, so I thought about subclassing `A` with a "wrapper" that simply adds `extra_data`. Not sure how to initialize `super()` though.

```py
class A:
    """
    This class is out of my control. I know nothing about its internals,
    or the data it contains. __slots__ prevents more attributes being added.
    """

    __slots__ = ["data"]

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

# The initialization happens elsewhere. I don't know how A is initialized.
a = A([1, 2, 3])

# Won't work:
#
# a.t = 1
# setattr(a, "t", 1)
#
# AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 't'


class Wrap(A):
    def __init__(self, a, extra_data):
        self.extra_data = extra_data
        super().__init__(a)  # ??


w = Wrap(a, [27])
print(w.data)        # [1, 2, 3]
print(w.extra_data)  # [27]
```

Any hints?

Comment: This sounds like a job for composition, not inheritance. (It would sound like a job for weak references, but weakrefs don't work with `A`, so `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` isn't an option.)

Comment: @user2357112 Would it be possible to have the composed object work just like an instance of `A`?

Comment: How could it when you claim you don't know anything about `A`?

Comment: @chepner I don't understand the question.

Comment: There are ways to sort of fake it, partially, but those ways have too many pitfalls. You'd just be creating too many problems for yourself down the line.

Comment: I guess there's no way around a `__slots__` setting then. Too bad.

Comment: Where is this object coming from that you can't find the source code that created it? Your question is misleading, as it implies you *have* the source code that defines `A` and the call that created `a`, but you can't *change* it. With read-only source code, it would be trivial to define the subclass you want; without that, I don't see how you can possibly define a valid subclass.

Comment: @chepner I _could_ of couse dig out _something_, but it's infeasible. Everything is internal and prone to change at any time. That's why I don't want to rely on the specifics of `A`. I had hoped I could "just add data" to one of its instances, perhaps there could have been be a way to create a subclass instance with an `a`, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you get an object instance, but are not able to directly create it. And the class uses `__slots__` preventing any additional attribute.

In that case, I cannot imagine anything else that a *composition wrapper*: a class having a `A` attribute and the additional attributes that you need. Something like:

```
class Wrap:
   def __init__(self, a, extra_data):
        self.a = a
        self.extra_data = extra_data
```

If you want a `Wrap` instance to be used where a `A` one could be, you should try to use delegation:

```
class Wrap:
   def __init__(self, a, extra_data):
        self.a = a
        self.extra_data = extra_data
   # delegate A_method_x from A class
   def A_method_x(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.a.A_method_x(*args, **kwargs)    
   # delegate an attribute (say A_attr_y) as a property
   @property
   def A_attr_y(self):
       return self.a.A_attr_y
   @A_attr_y.setter
   def set_A_attr_y(self, val):
       self.a.A_attr_y = val
```

Of course a `Wrap` instance is only a *duck typing* instance of `A`, so calls to `isinstance` would fail...

---

If the class `A` is too complex, and explicitely handling every attribute would be a maintenance nightmare, you could set up some *dynamic proxying* through the special methods `__getattr__` (fires when an unknown attribute is asked on an object) and `__setattr__` (used to set attributes on an object):

```
class A:
    """
    This class is out of my control. I know nothing about its internals,
    or the data it contains. __slots__ prevents more attributes being added.
    """

    __slots__ = ["data"]

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def foo(self, inval):
        return f"A.foo called with {inval} - data={self.data}"

class Wrap(A):
    def __init__(self, a, extra_data):
        self.a = a
        self.extra_data = extra_data

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in A.__slots__:
            setattr(self.a, name, value)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # process A attributes
        if name in A.__slots__:   
            a = object.__getattribute__(self, "a")
            return getattr(a, name)
        # process A methods
        if hasattr(A, name):
            a = object.__getattribute__(self, "a")
            return getattr(a, name)
        # process Wrap attributes
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Demo in an interactive session:

```
a = A(12)
w = Wrap(a, 'ab')
w.data = 14
w.foo('x')
'A.foo called with x - data=14'
w.another_data = 'y'
w.data
14
w.z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    w.z
  File "C:\...py", line 33, in __getattribute__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Wrap' object has no attribute 'z'
isinstance(w, A)
True
```

Comment: Class `A` is so big and changes so often that is unfeasible to duck type all functions. And yeah, it not being of (sub)class `A` would also be a problem...

Comment: @NicoSchlömer: Please see my edit for an automatic proxying way pretending to be a subclass